# I'm using Asp.net with c# code, I have a page with a gridview I would like to use javascript without any ajax to filter the rows

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

```
function Search_Gridview(strKey, strGV) {
    var strData = strKey.value.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    var tblData = document.getElementById(strGV);
    var rowData;
    for (var i = 1; i < tblData.rows.length; i++) {
        rowData = tblData.rows[i].innerHTML;
        var styleDisplay = 'none';
        for (var j = 0; j < strData.length; j++) {
            if (rowData.toLowerCase().indexOf(strData[j]) >= 0)
                styleDisplay = '';
            else {
                styleDisplay = 'none';
                break;
            }
        }
        tblData.rows[i].style.display = styleDisplay;
    }
}
```

in the grid I wrote this code but it is search only for one page in grid view I want it in all grid view pages

and then in textbox I use

```
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server" onkeyup="Search_Gridview(this, 'GridView1')"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: i have posted answer for you ? have you tried this

Answer (score 0):

There is special engine Based on javascipt and MVVC ; **AngularJS**
That is used to perform these functions in good speed.

> AngularJS lets you extend HTML vocabulary for your application. The resulting environment is extraordinarily expressive, readable, and quick to develop.

[Angular](https://angularjs.org/)

**EXAMPLE**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example97-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
  

  
</head>
<body ng-app="">
  <div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

Search: <input ng-model="searchText">
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
Any: <input ng-model="search.$"> <br>
Name only <input ng-model="search.name"><br>
Phone only <input ng-model="search.phone"><br>
Equality <input type="checkbox" ng-model="strict"><br>
<table id="searchObjResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
    <td>{{friendObj.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friendObj.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```